# How to add json-serde jar to Spark SQL using Hive?

Tags: json, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to query a hive table which uses a JSON SerDe. I have added the SerDe jar to the driver classpath of the program but i am still unable to query the table from Spark. I get `message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe not found)` exception. How can i add this jar to Spark classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your Jars to Spark Conf :

```
SparkConf sc = new SparkConf();
sc.setJars("typically_absolute_hdfs_path");
```

In Python :

```
conf = (SparkConf() .setJars("local"))
```

Comment: I am using the python API and i don't think there is a setJars method

Comment: You should be able to do this in Python : conf = (SparkConf()
         .setJars("local"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)